# Distribution of minimum separation of 3 random points in a unit square

Tags: pr.probability

Johan Philip derives the PDF for the distance between 2 random points in a unit square: http://www.math.kth.se/~johanph/habc.pdf

What is the PDF for the minimum separation of 3 random points in a unit square? (where the maximum minimum separation is known to be sqrt(6)-sqrt(2): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square

Similar question for k points where 3 <= k <= 9 (for which the maximum minimum separation is known precisely). Similar question for unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

I know you seek the PDF in an explicit
form, but here is the distribution empirically,
for 100,000 trials, of the minimum separation among
three points within a unit square:

 [image: Histogram min 3 pts]

The mean minimum distance is 0.305 and the median is 0.287.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, looks Poisson

Comment: Thanks. We've simulated the PDF and CDF for 10^7 points for k from 3 through 6. It looks like a Weibull or a Beta (suitably normalized to [0,1]). The CDF of a Weibull seems to match the data exactly for 10^6 simulations. Also a PP-plot looks like a straight line. However, a Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test rejects the null hypothesis that it's a Weibull (as estimated from maximum likelihood) at the 0.01 level.